# SetInterval causes too many re-renders React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I would like to put setInterval in my React project to add 1 for each second but I got an error like in title of this post.
js:

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
       setInterval(setActiveTab(prevTab => {
           if (prevTab === 3) return 0
           console.log('hi')
           return prevTab += 1
               
       }), 1000)
   
   })
```

Comment: you should consider the other answer. The answer you selected is not good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You're not passing a function to `setInterval`, you're **calling** `setActiveTab` and passing its return value into `setInterval`.
2. If you were passing in a function, you'd be adding a **new** repeated timer every time your componennt ran. See the documentation — [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

   > By default, effects run after every completed render...

   And [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

   > The `setInterval()` method... **repeatedly** calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

   *(my emphasis)*

   Starting a new repeating timer **every time** your component re-renders creates a **lot** of repeating timers.
3. Your component will leave the interval timer running if the component is unmounted. It should stop the interval timer.

To fix it, pass in a function, add a dependency array, and add a cleanup callback to stop the interval:

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(() => { // *** A function
        setActiveTab(prevTab => {
            if (prevTab === 3) return 0;
            console.log("?ghi");
            return prevTab += 1;
        });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {              // *** Clear the interval on unmount
        clearInterval(handle);  // ***
    };                          // ***
}, []); // *** Empty dependency array = only run on mount
```

---

Side note: Assuming you don't need the `console.log`, that state setter callback function can be simpler by using the remainder operator:

```
setActiveTab(prevTab => (prevTab + 1) % 3);
```

Comment: Super helpful, thanks. I was seeing jerky behavior, it turns out I always had to run `clearInterval` at the end of the `useEffect` function even if I was also clearing it in `setActiveTab` once the count was reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setActiveTab((prevTab) => {
        if (prevTab !== 3) {
          return (prevTab += 1);
        } else {
          return 0;
        } // console.log("hi");
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Comment: This might work

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just dumping code. That makes it useful for other people.

Comment: Initially you passed `setActiveTab`   in `setInterval` function on the place where it takes a function (or say callback function)  . So I put there a callback function inside which `setActiveTab` is going on

Comment: for safety measure always put an array as second argument of `useEffect`

`useEffect(()=>{}, [])`

Comment: You should just edit your answer instead of putting it in the comments.

Comment: I have explained what I wrote as answer

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the description. Comments aren't meant for this.